# Does Npgsql support community version of postgres?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I read from the enterprise db website that only the Postgres standard server and advanced server support Npgsql.

But am not sure if
 1. Npgsql will not work with community version at all ?? or
 2. It is just that it is not packaged along with community version,but I can use npgsql to connect and work with postgresql from .Net

Can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read from the enterprise db website that only the Postgres standard
>   server and advanced server support Npgsql.

EnterpriseDB is not the same as PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL is PostgreSQL, it's not a "community version" from EnterpriseDB. EnterpriseDB Server is a fork of PostgreSQL, not the other way around.

And yes, [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) does work with PostgreSQL, it was created for PostgreSQL:

> Npgsql is a .Net Data Provider for Postgresql. It allows any program
>   developed for .Net framework to access database server. It is
>   implemented in 100% C# code. **Works with Postgresql 7.x and above.**

Comment: Great. So this means I have to download PostgreSQL from the postgresql site. Is it from here http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/ ?

Comment: If you're looking for PostgreSQL, get PostgreSQL. If you want EnterpriseDB Server, get their product. EnterpriseDB does host the one-click installers for PostgreSQL: http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload You can find this link also on postgresql.org: http://www.postgresql.org/download/